# Rails whenever gem not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I am new on cron jobs in Rails and I want to do it using 'whenever' gem. This is what I have tried so far.

Gemfile

```
gem 'whenever'
```

Mailer.rb

```
 def new_test
    Rails.logger.debug '===========whenever is working================'
 end
```

Schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
  runner 'Mailers.new_test'
end
```

But this does not do anything. Where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you post an error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`whenever` actually does not automatically run that job for you. It is just an easy way for you to create corresponding cronjob on your system. You need to run the following command on your project to update your crontab

```
whenever -i
```

Regards

Comment: sure would be nice if they had this documented on the readme page

Answer (score 0):

There seems to two error in your code :

in your scheduler.rb you are not calling mailer properly. You write `Mailers.new_test` it should be `Mailer.new_test` if `Mailer` is a simple model. And if it's mailer ie. override from class `ActionMailer` then it should be `Mailer.new_test.deliver`.

In case of `Mailer` is simple model then files should be :

Mailer.rb

new_test should be class method to call like `Mailer.new_test` not an instance method

```
def self.new_test # Should be a class method not instance
  Rails.logger.debug '===========whenever is working================'
end
```

Schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
  runner 'Mailer.new_test'
end
```

And if mailer is instance of action mailer then :

Mailer.rb

```
def new_test
  Rails.logger.debug '===========whenever is working================'
end
```

Schedule.rb

```
every 1.minutes do
  runner 'Mailer.new_test.deliver'
end
```